# Cannot make double jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have problem when making a 2d platformer game with Unity 5 about cannot perform double jump and just perform one jump for my playable character. Please check out what's wrong from my script below:

**Player Movement.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float forwardSpeed = 1f;
    public float jumpHeight;

    bool doJump = false;
    bool canJumpAgain;
    bool isGrounded;
    float deathCooldown;
    Animator animator;
    Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

    void Awake () {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {
        animator = transform.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

        if(animator == null) {
            Debug.LogError("Didn't find animator!");
        }    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        isGrounded = true;
        //for movement with infinite run to right
        myRigidbody.AddForce( Vector2.right * forwardSpeed );
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
    }

    void OnCollisionStay2D (Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && isGrounded  && !doJump) {
            myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jumpHeight); 
                animator.SetTrigger("DoJump");
                isGrounded = false;
                canJumpAgain = true;
                doJump = true;
            }

//perform double jump but failed
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && doJump && !isGrounded) {
                myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jumpHeight); 
                animator.SetTrigger("DoJump");
                Debug.Log ("yes");
                canJumpAgain = true;
                doJump = false;
            }

            if (canJumpAgain) {
                //myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                myRigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
                animator.SetTrigger("DoJump");
                Debug.Log ("yes1");    
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D (Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            isGrounded = false;
            GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().isTrigger = false;
        }

        transform.parent = null;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Other)
    {    
    }    
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far to diagnose the problem? Which piece of code isn't behaving as you expected it to?

Comment: @Jon Skeet It just show "yes" from  "Debug.Log ("yes");" and "yes1" from "Debug.Log ("yes1");"   on console log but cannot perform double jump.

Comment: Okay, so it's got into the "canJumpAgain" bit which is presumably what you're referring to as "double jump" - so have you checked that `jumpHeight` is non-zero? Is there any reason you're using AddForce rather than setting the velocity, as you do for the single jump?

Comment: @jon Skeet for 'jumpHeight' I already set to 7.00f on editor. My reason using Addforce just trying to fix about double jump problem or not.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand the second sentence of your comment at all - but if you're getting into the relevant block, then it *sounds* like `AddForce` doesn't quite do what you expect it to. (I don't know much at all about Unity, but that's where I'd look if I were you.)

Comment: May I ask why you set 'isGrounded' to true every Update() call? :D Doesn't make sense

Comment: @jon skeet Same with me I still not pro about unity

Comment: @TuukkaX Because if I remove 'isGrounded' and set to false cannot perform first jump

Comment: Does the character completely ignore the second jump attempt or does it do something else (like fall slower)?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis just completely ignore for second jump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can resolved with my way please check out my script below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float forwardSpeed = 1f;
    public float jumpHeight;
    bool doJump;
    bool canJumpAgain;
    bool isGrounded;
    float deathCooldown;
    Animator animator;
    Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    private bool canJump = false;
    private int availableJumps = 1;
    float jumpForce = 0f; // Force added when the player jumps.
    public float firstJumpForce = 0f;
    public float secondJumpForce = 0f;

    void Awake () {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {
        animator = transform.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

        if(animator == null) {
            Debug.LogError("Didn't find animator!");
        }    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        isGrounded = true;
        //for movement with infinite run to right
        myRigidbody.AddForce( Vector2.right * forwardSpeed );
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && isGrounded) {
            doJump = true;
        }
    }

void FixedUpdate () {
        if(doJump && canJump)
        {
            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jumpHeight); 
            animator.SetTrigger("DoJump");

            // Can the player jump again??
            availableJumps--;
            if (availableJumps <= 0){
                canJump = false;
            } else {
                //I modify the second jump force
                jumpForce = secondJumpForce;
            }
            doJump = false;
        }

    }

void OnCollisionStay2D (Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            canJump = true;
            availableJumps = 1;
            jumpForce = firstJumpForce;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D (Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            isGrounded = false;
            GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().isTrigger = false;
        }

        transform.parent = null;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Other)
    {    
    }    
}
```

I cannot remove "isGrounded = true;" on void update section because cannot perform first jump although already tried from TuukkaX's solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this will fix the problem you're facing. Do not set *isGrounded* to true every Update() call. On the *OnTriggerEnter2D*() you wan't to have something like this: `if (other.gameObject.tag == "ground") isGrounded = true;` On the *OnTriggerExit2D*() you need to have this: `if (other.gameObject.tag == "ground") isGrounded = false;` Set the floor tag in the Unity inspector to *ground*. Explained:  Before each double jump you're checking if *isGrounded* is false, however this will be always true since you're making it true every frame.